# data:dump a selected table Yamldb

Tags: ruby, database, ruby-on-rails-4, yaml, data-dump

I have been using YamlDb to save the state of my database.
And use the rake task to dump the contents of Rails database to db/data.yml

```
rake db:data:dump
```

I also use the rake task to load the contents of db/data.yml into the database at times.

```
rake db:data:load
```

**I am not sure if this has been asked before, but is there anyway to Dump one or two selected tables as oppose to the entire DB? if so how?**

Comment: Are you using sqlite as your database?

Comment: I am using Postgresql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone wants to be able to dump/load individual tables with yaml_db on Rails 4.

You can use this gem

```
gem 'yaml_db', :git => 'git://github.com/ballin22s/yaml_db.git'
```

Answer (score 1):

I looked into the [YamlDb](https://github.com/ludicast/yaml_db) gem and it was a simple change to modify the rake task to include an argument which takes a parameter of table name.  I've forked the repo and made the necessary changes [here](https://github.com/Ploonky/yaml_db).  I'll work on getting the changes merged into the gem but for now you can add this repo to your Gemfile like this:

```
gem 'yamldb', :git => 'https://github.com/Ploonky/yaml_db.git'
```

Comment: awesome. So would i just call rake db:data:load users ? Or how can i pass the argument?

Comment: Check the README on the repo for full syntax but your case would be rake db:data:load["users"]

Comment: For some reason I keep getting this error when i bundle install. Gemfile syntax error: gem 'yamldb', :git => https:^//github.com/Ploonky/yaml_db.git

Comment: You need quotes around the git repo path.

Comment: whenever I try to do this  rake db:data:dump["likes"] using Rails 4. I get this error...NoMethodError: undefined method `[]=' for #<ActiveRecord::Result:0x007fb315bca4b0>

Comment: I can update my fork of the gem but it looks like the original project now allows dumping database tables to directory. Let me know if you want to migrate to the original or want me to make the fix.

Comment: Can you make the fix please....or update the code to demonstrate how to dump a database table to directory using the original project.